# How can I set lease duration on azure fileshare leased file?

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-storage-files, fileshare, storage-file-share

I am trying to set expiry for acquired leased as 1 min. This is my code

```
var shareClient = new ShareClient(connectionString, "testfileshare");
shareClient.CreateIfNotExists();
var fileClient = shareClient.GetRootDirectoryClient().GetFileClient("test.xml"); 
var leaseClient = fileClient.GetShareLeaseClient();
                
leaseClient.Acquire(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
 var leaseDuration = fileClient.GetProperties().Value.LeaseDuration;
```

With above code leaseDuration is set to infinite. I would like to set this to 1 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set the lease duration for a file in a file share. You can only acquire an infinite lease on a file (though it is possible to acquire a finite lease on a file share).

From the [`REST API documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-file#request-headers):

[image]